In SSL/TLS, why do we need 2 public keys?
Server adds its public key in SSL Certificate and send it to client.
However, Client already has the public key. If it already has a public key, then it does not need to have server's public key which came within the SSL Certificate.
Why do we need to add public key in SSL Certificate? In case of client does not have public key of the server?
Found the answer, I think I misunderstood some of the process.

Why don't you add the answer you found as an Answer; that way, it'd help if someone else had the same question

I’m voting to close this question because the questioner seems to have understood how PKI in general works now, and this has been explained at many places.

Usually the client has the certificate / public key of the Certification Authority as a trust anchor. Then it gets a chain of certificates ending with the server certificate, which is checked using certification path validation. Of course, the information in the certificate should also make sense; for SSL it is important that it indicates trust for the given server by name.
Finally the server needs to show that it possesses the private key for the public key in the server certificate. Nowadays this is usually performed by signing the handshake (including the parts that establish the session keys). Once that signature is verified the server entity has been authenticated.
So no, the client doesn't already have the servers public key, unless the trust anchor is the server certificate itself. This is sometimes the case if certificate pinning and / or self-signed certificates are used.

All this is called a PKI or Public Key Infrastructure. When X.509 certificates are used - for instance for TLS - then it is often called PKIX.

Could you turn this a bit 101?

@kelalaka I thought I'd answer before we'd get an answer with all the wrong phrases. I can close the question though, I think the questioner found the answer.
